# Error while deploying through hudson in tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, jpa, hudson

I have a maven project which runs flawlessly on my local environment. But when I deploy it over our DEV environment, it gives out the following error while deploying and stops any further deployment steps and the server just goes up.

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator" was loaded by
log4j:ERROR [org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@19968e23] whereas object of type
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator" was loaded by [WebappClassLoader
  context: /cloud
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@19968e23
].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate configurator [org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.att.security.web.servlet.filters.CSPCookieFilter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I see this in the catalina logs when the while deploying. The deployment is always a success but the application does not work properly. It started occurring when I upgraded my application from spring 3.2.0 to 3.2.7 as I wanted to use the JPA 2.1 specification and call a procedure directly.

As a workaround, I have to wipe out the workspace and re-deploy the build via hudson and then manually restart the tomcat 7.0.52 server for the application to work properly. In that case also, the error comes but the application works fine.

My POM looks like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javax.version>3.0.1</javax.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.4.Final</hibernate.version>
    <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    <ehcache.version>2.8.0</ehcache.version>
    <apache.poi-version>3.9</apache.poi-version>
    <junit-version>4.8.1</junit-version>
    <mockito-version>1.8.5</mockito-version>
</properties>

    <!-- utilities to convert java objects to JSON objects -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Java Servlet APIs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java Mail API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for logger used by spring frameworks -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Recent changes I have done to my application: 
1. Including the Javamail API dependency 
2. Upgrading the spring-jpa-data dependecy to 1.6.0 from 1.3.4 
3. Upgrading the spring base version to 3.2.7 from 3.2.0

I searched the web but did not find something working for me. Please guide. The application will be going to PROD in a week and I don't want to stick with my workaround.

Any help is pre-appreciated as I don't have the reputation to do the same after posting the question :)

Comment: "as I wanted to use the JPA 2.1 specification". So why have you got JPA API (javax.persistence) 1.0 in your CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 1):

You must have placed log4j.jar in both Tomcat libs and your web application libs. You have to chose and keep one of them.